# How draw from an intersection down to x axes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Based on [How to draw in pgfplot until intersection with plot line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211017/how-to-draw-in-pgfplot-until-intersection-with-plot-line) I have come up with this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0,ymax=100,xmin=5E-13,xmax=3E-4,
xlabel=Concentration,
ylabel=Effect (\%),
axis lines=left,
width=2\marginparwidth,
height=1.4\marginparwidth,
ytick={0,25,50,75,100},
xmode = log,
tick label style = {font=\footnotesize},
]
\addplot [color=black, name path=P] coordinates {
    (1E-4, 0)
    (1E-5, 0)
    (1E-6, 2)
    (1E-7, 21)
    (1E-8, 66)
    (1E-9, 88)
    (1E-10, 94)
    (1E-11, 95)
    (1E-12, 96)
    };
\addplot [only marks] coordinates {
    (1E-4, 0)
    (1E-5, 0)
    (1E-6, 2)
    (1E-7, 21)
    (1E-8, 66)
    (1E-9, 88)
    (1E-10, 94)
    (1E-11, 95)
    (1E-12, 96)
    };

\path [name path=A] (axis cs:1E-12, 50) -- (axis cs:1E-4, 50);
\path [name intersections={of=A and P}];
\draw[->, thick] (axis cs:1E-12, 50) -- (intersection-1); 
\path [name path=B] (axis cs:1E-12, 0) -- (axis cs:1E-4, 0);
\draw[->, thick] (intersection-1) -| B);
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, I want to draw another arrow down from the end of the last arrow and to the x-axes. I thought this would be easy but seems it was not. Clearly I can't just draw a `-|` line between the things as I tried. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A job for the perpendicular coordinate system; you can say something like

```
\draw[->, thick,red] (intersection-1) -- ({intersection-1}|-{axis cs:0,0});
```

[image]

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0,ymax=100,xmin=5E-13,xmax=3E-4,
xlabel=Concentration,
ylabel=Effect (\%),
axis lines=left,
width=2\marginparwidth,
height=1.4\marginparwidth,
ytick={0,25,50,75,100},
xmode = log,
tick label style = {font=\footnotesize},
]
\addplot [color=black, name path=P] coordinates {
    (1E-4, 0)
    (1E-5, 0)
    (1E-6, 2)
    (1E-7, 21)
    (1E-8, 66)
    (1E-9, 88)
    (1E-10, 94)
    (1E-11, 95)
    (1E-12, 96)
    };
\addplot [only marks] coordinates {
    (1E-4, 0)
    (1E-5, 0)
    (1E-6, 2)
    (1E-7, 21)
    (1E-8, 66)
    (1E-9, 88)
    (1E-10, 94)
    (1E-11, 95)
    (1E-12, 96)
    };
\path [name path=A] (axis cs:1E-12, 50) -- (axis cs:1E-4, 50);
\path [name intersections={of=A and P}];
\draw[->, thick] (axis cs:1E-12, 50) -- (intersection-1); 
\draw[->, thick,red] 
(intersection-1) -- ({intersection-1}|-{axis cs:0,0}); 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have added `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`, what does that mean?

Comment: @jonalv: This will configure the compatibility layer. In this example, it is perfectly safe to delete that line. I'll do so in an edit. For a detailed description of the compatibility layer (basically it activates/deactivates new features), see the `pgfplots` manual.

Comment: Is that why I get a warning about versions?

Comment: @jonalv Yes. With the most recent (up to today) release of `pgfplots`, you should say `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` to prevent the warning.

Comment: Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139690/dos-and-donts-of-pgfplotssetcompat-newest/139695#139695 on a discussion about `compat`